# Double value with comma on MacOS - system locale

Tags: php

I have trouble with `Zend Server 6` Free Edition and `MacOS 10.7`.

`Zend` uses system configuration for locale. If I use double variable as parameter in `SQL` query `PHP` typing double value with `comma` and `SQL` query is wrong.

I try `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US')`, but it has no effect. `PHP` locale is still `cs_CZ`.

How can I change locale for double value?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong where, can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C')`; if that doesn't work, check the return value and the effect with

```
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C'), "\n";
echo 4*atan(1), "\n";
```

e. g.